# how to make a mfc dialog's height unsizeable?

Tags: mfc

i am playing with a MFC github project xtrader on github. I managed to get it up running and having one question i cannot understand.

This project is a dialog based MFC based app, the main dialog xTraderDlg, when i run it, i found the height of the dialog is not sizable, however the width does.

i have being read this source for quite some time and review every place that handles SetWindowPos() or OnSize(). There is not traces how this done. Even i comment out the OnSize() or OnInitDialog(), the height remains unchangeable.

the code has some tricks to save the width and height in a config file and reload it next time it is up. but i believe it doesnot matter.

the code also has this line. 
::SetWindowPos(m_hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
However even i remove this line the result is still the same. And SWP_NOSIZE wont cause only the height unsizeable. it is a myth to me indeed.

Can anyone advise me why? main dialog code is here.

https://github.com/lpswufe/xTrader/blob/master/xTraderDlg.cpp

Answer (score 1):

This is done in OnGetMinMaxInfo [WM_GETMINMAXINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).